# Encode a 4 Length string using different 4 bit binary numbers

Tags: java

I am trying to make a function that turns a binary number into letters according to the positions of the one's inside of it.

For example if i had the binary number : 0101

I want to take the String "LUDR" and effectively multiply them together to get
: "UR".

I have the 4 bit binary numbers in an array and the string that i want to 'multiply' them with is always going to be "LUDR".

I will give more examples..
binary number of : 1011 gives "LDR"
binary number of : 0001 gives "R"

EDIT:

the code i have already written :

```
String[][] binVals = new String[10][10];
//my function to fill up with 4 bit binary values so i can get 100 in total
//just read from file so that's why it's a string array
String mazeWallRemove = "LURD";
//I need to write some function to turn the binary values in to some string
String[][] unCodedWalls = new String[10][10]//into this array
```

my question is what functions can i use to 'multiply' the binVals and the "LURD" string to get the string output(in the form as shown above)

I can just write 15 if statments converting each binary value from the array into an integer and then just saying:

```
for(int a = 0; a < 10; a++){
   for(int b = 0; b < 10; b++){
      if(binVals[a][b] == 1){
         uncodedWalls[a][b] = "R"
      } // lots more else if statements
   }
}
```

this method is horribly inefficient and so i'm looking for a more efficient way to do it instead of making tons of if statements.

Comment: what code you have done so far.

Comment: Can you explain the question more elaborately.

Comment: We understand the exercise you're trying to work, but what is your question *for us*?  We are not a code-writing service, but we will help you with specific coding questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the charAt method available in String class to construct the string you need. Pass the binary number and string you want to multiply to this method. This will check the character in the binary String is 1 and get the corresponding value from the original String and append it.

```
public String multiply(String value, String binary) {
    String finalString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i++) {
        if (binary.charAt(i) == '1') {
            finalString+=value.charAt(i);
        }
    }       
    return finalString;

}
```

Comment: Although it's great that you want to help, note that you just did somebody's homework for them. Instead of posting a full code solution, maybe consider walking them through the process of solving the problem themselves?

Comment: Ignoring the argument about homework, this answer would function fine, but note that when appending to a String within a loop you'll get better efficiency by using a `StringBuilder`, especially if you pass the constructor a sensible initial capacity which is going to be sufficient to hold the final length of the assembled string sequence.

Comment: this was not any homework i was coding a visual and interactable maze generator and solver in processing, where the maze solver was a genetic algorithm. it was a while ago and it doesn't really matter now but just wanted to clarify.